# Android: Alarm not working

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

i am trying to activate an alarm 3 seconds into the future (for test purposes), which opens a notification message. It is not working.

This is the button that triggers the alarm:

```
public void testButton() {


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000, alarmIntent);

}
```

This is the AlertReceiver class. Do i understand it right, that it should call onReceive() automatically when the Intent gets started? Because the notification works if i call that method manually (not over an Intent but over an instantiated Object of that class.
Also according to a tutorial TaskStackBuilder.create(context) should actually get passed an activity and not a context, but i cant call getActivity().

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String mTitle = "test";
private String mText = "test text";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

    Notification.Builder nb = notificationUtils.getChannelNotification(mTitle, mText);

    Intent startApp = intent;

    TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    tStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(startApp);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    nb.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationUtils.getManager().notify(101, nb.build());
}
```

}

This is the NotificationUtils class:

```
public class NotificationUtils extends ContextWrapper {

private NotificationManager mManager;
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "task_reminder_channel";
public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Task Reminder Channel";

public NotificationUtils(Context base) {
    super(base);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannels();
    }
}

@TargetApi(26)
public void createChannels() {
    NotificationChannel reminderChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    reminderChannel.enableLights(true);
    reminderChannel.enableVibration(true);
    reminderChannel.setLightColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    reminderChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    getManager().createNotificationChannel(reminderChannel);
}

public NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (mManager == null) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mManager;
}

@TargetApi(26)
public Notification.Builder getChannelNotification(String title, String body) {

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timelapse_primary)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}

public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotificationApiUnder26(String title, String body) {
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timelapse_primary)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Where exactly do you have the `<receiver>` element for `AlertReceiver` in the manifest?

Comment: I tried different things. At the moment i have this:    
<receiver
        android:name=".AlertReceiver">
        </receiver>

Comment: Where is it, though? It needs to be between the `<application>` tags, but not inside anything else, like an `<activity>` or `<service>`. I should also point out that your alarm might take longer than 3 seconds to actually fire, so you should give it a little bit.

Comment: I had it outside of <application>, under <manifest> and <uses-permission> Now that i put it inside there, it works. Thats already really nice because i thought i had problems with my code. Just one weird thing. It doesnt wait 3 seconds, it waits longer and it seems like the time varies.

Comment: `AlarmManager` isn't meant for short intervals like that. Sometimes it takes a bit to get initialized. Also, the `set()` method has been inexact since KitKat.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, maybe you can tell me if i have to put anything in "intent filter" in my xml file?

Comment: Nope. The `Intent` is specifically targeting `AlertReceiver.class`. Just that `<receiver>` element you showed is sufficient.